# Sort dataframe by date column stored as string

Tags: python, time-series, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe named `df1`.

I want to **sort** data frame *month* column according to month (Jan, Feb, March..).

For that I used code:

```
sorted_df = df1.sort_values(by='month')
print(sorted_df)
```

but the output is sorted by **alphabetic order of month column**.

I think the reason for that in this month column data type is **object** so month column is sorted by alphabetic order.

**The question is**: how sort values in column *month* in correct order (according to order of months in year)?

My dataframe:

[image: alphabetic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest first separating the month column into `day` and `month` using `str.split('-')`

```
# create test data
df = pd.DataFrame(['20-Apr', '19-Mar', '4-Dec'], columns=['month'])
# create day column
df['day'] = 0 
split =  df['month'].str.split('-', expand=True)
df['day'], df['month'] = split[0], split[1]
```

Now that month is seperated, you can change it to categorical such that it can be custom sorted

```
df['month'] = pd.Categorical(df['month'], ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'])
```

Now you can sort

```
df.sort_values("month")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @A Kareem why pd.categorical function? from this function what we can do??

Comment: Because then when you sort them, it relies on the ordering of the initial list passed to it,
You should read the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html)
From the documentation: "Ordered Categoricals can be sorted according to the custom order of the categories and can have a min and max value."

Comment: Finally I want to concatenate this month and day column. So I went to concatenate this month and day column but there had error,**unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Categorical' and 'str'** so how I can concatenate this month and day column. `df['final_date'] = df['month'] +' '+ df['day']
print(df)` This code I have used above concatenation.

Comment: @A Kareem thanks a lot. I did a concatenation part successfully. I accepted your answer as correct one.

Answer (score 4):

Your `month` column is really a partial date (i.e. the *year* is missing), but you could still just convert that column to a proper date format and then sort.
You will have to specify a format, so the parser knows roughly what to do.

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(["20-Apr"], format="%d-%b")
df.sort_values("date")   # ascending by default
```

Without any year information, it will add the year as 1900.

---

If you want to add e.g. this year, you could do the following, adding `12*20` months to the new date column:

```
df["fixed_date"] = df.date.apply(lambda x: pd.tseries.offsets.shift_month(x, 12*20))
```